# For loop over every child elements

Tags: xquery

With my XML

```
<products>
    <product id="12" type="modell">
        <attribute type="image">nose.jpg</attribute>
        <product id="13" type="kid">
            <attribute type="image">face.jpg</attribute>
        </product>
    </product>
    <product id="22" type="modell">
        ...
    </product>
</products>
```

and xquery I except to get every attribute with type `image` under my product with id `12`.

What I tried so far:

```
 data(for $image in //product[@id = '12']/*/attribute[@type='IMAGE']
 return $image)
```

Which will not work (without `*` I'm getting only the `nose.jpg`), but I m searching for a way to return `face.jpg` and `nose.jpg`.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `descendant-or-self::attribute` axis step, abbreviated `//attribute` instead, which matches in the whole subtree (while `/*/attribute` only "skips" one level):

```
data(for $image in //product[@id = '12']//attribute[@type='IMAGE']
return $image)
```

*(I was required to change `IMAGE` to lower case to match your input, though)*

Comment: The solution was so close... TY!